# zend frame work index action giving 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

i got a strange problem today i tried to fixed it by google no luck so far.

problem is i have a IndexController.php file in zend framework app and it has simple action called about but when i tried to access it via

`http://mysite/index/about` it will give me 404

and if tried

`http://mysite/Index/about` it will load properly (with Capital I) this casesitive problem  is giving only to index controller my other controllers are working fine im on ubuntu

here my htaccess file and i have enabled mod_rewirte and allowe_overried has set to all

```
# Rewrite Rules for Zend Framework
RewriteEngine On
# Add File Names or Extentions of files that you want to be able to access
#RewriteRule !alternate.php|.(js|css|ico|bmp|gif|jpg|png|xml|xsl|eot|svg|ttf|woff)$ index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

# Security: Do not allow Browsing of Directories
Options -Indexes

# additional headers related to security
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # defends against 'ClickJacking' attacks by disallowing this site to be displayed in an IFRAME
    Header always append X-Frame-Options DENY
    # helps prevent attacks based on MIME-type confusion by rejecting css/js responses with incorrect MIME type
    Header always append X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>
```

if you guys have any idea please post

thanks

Comment: Try removing `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d`.

Comment: Thansk for the comment but no luck @faa

Comment: Forgot to mention the previous [OR] has to b removed too. Is there a directory called `Index`?

Comment: @faa i have removed [OR] no luck and i dont have a folder called Index  thanks

Comment: That's odd. Maybe there is a symlink `index`, could you try removing `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]`

Comment: totally odd :) nothing coming on my way so far .. thanks mate btw

Comment: I see you edited your previous comment. Is there a directory called `index`? If not, I am out of ideas except making sure the options are correct by adding this line: `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews`.

Comment: hey you are genius now its working after adding Otions +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews awesome and put this as answer i can accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line to make sure the options are correct:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
```